# How to load bytes in a __m128i in a specific position

Tags: c++, image-processing, x86, sse, simd

I need to load 4 bytes stored consecutively in an array in a specific position of a __m128i variable, namely to be able to do many int32_t sums, 4 at a time, storing all partial results.

For example:

```
const unsigned int SIZE = 2000000;
const unsigned int STEP = 100;

unsigned char* inBuffer = new char[SIZE];
//Fill inBuffer
const unsigned char* a = inBuffer;

int32_t* outBuffer = new int32_t[SIZE/STEP*4];
int32_t* result = outBuffer;

__m128i sum = _mm_setzero_si128 ()
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i+=STEP) {
    __m128i value = _mm_set_epi32 (a[3],a[2],a[1],a[0]);
    sum = __mm_add_epi32(sum,value);
    _mm_storeu_si128 ((__m128i*)result,sum);
    a+=STEP;
    result+=4;
    }

//Print outBuffer

delete[] inBuffer;
delete[] outBuffer;
```

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do so

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here of course is this line:

```
__m128i value = _mm_set_epi32 (a[3],a[2],a[1],a[0]);
```

However a decent compiler should generate fairly efficient code for this. Take a look at the output (`gcc -O3 -S ...`) - if it's more than a few instructions then you may want to consider doing the load/unpack operations yourself.

Comment: Can I load just 4 bytes in a __m128i? (Loading 16 and throwing away 12 doesn't sound efficient) If yes, I could then shuffle them. BTW, is it possible to know how many __m128i registers I could count on? Anything close to 10 would help for the rest of the processing I have and I could think about loading the 16 bytes in one go...

Comment: It would be much better if you could arrange to process contiguous data - then you could load 16 bytes at once, unpack it and process it as 4 x 4 x int32_t.

Comment: I was thinking about that! But I need 4 registers for 4 shuffling masks, 1 register for loading data, 1 register for one copy of the data, 4 registers for the 16 partial sum, isn't that too much?

Comment: Apparently it is too much, as working with a 32bit application I have apparently access to only 8 registers. I can still proceed with 3 masks and 3 partial sum, throwing away 4 bytes every time... I hope I will have time to try tomorrow...

Comment: Ok, I realized I need only 7 registers, the rest I can do with shifting operations, I hope I will be able to try soon :)

Comment: Don't worry too much about the perceived register count - the compiler will probably make a good job of whatever you code up using intrinsics and use fewer registers than you expect. Also go x86-64 as soon as you can - I typically see ~30% benefit on SIMD code when switching from x86 to x86-64.